# Visual Studio - Property Manager only top property is active

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have created several property sheets for various libraries. Each one works and their configurations are correct. I have verified this by entering the same dependencies, etc. into the project properties.

The various property sheets have been added through the property manager according to the type of build: x64, Debug / Release.

The problem is: Only the top property is read at build time, so the other library dependencies are not found. If I switch the other, the other libs fail.

This is using Visual Studio 13 Ultimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You need to make sure it has the MACRO call (%something) at the end of the line so it loads the next property. Otherwise, it will just stop there.